# File Upload Confusion

Tags: php, html

So I'm trying to create a form that a user can recursively call to in order to keep adding info.  Part of this requires that the user upload a photo.  I couldn't figure out what was wrong with my forms so I decided to simply move the file operation to a test environment and see if that was the cause of my woes.  For some odd reason the name of the file-input method I'm using isn't recognized when I use it in $_FILES['uploadfile'] and I'm wondering if any one might have any idea as to what I'm doing incorreclty.

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<form action="filetest.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="uploadfile" type="file" >
<input type="submit" value="test">
</body>
</html>

<html>
<?php
try{
    if( $_FILES['uploadfile']['size'] != 0 )
    {
        $directory = 'localhost/HoneysProject/rosterpics' ;
        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $directory.$_FILES['uploadfile']['name']) ;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception( "No file was uploaded" ) ;
    }
}
catch( Exception $error )
{
    echo $error ;
}
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, is that script you've posted **one file**? You can only access the `$_FILES` superglobal in the script your form posts to (named in your action - `filetest.php`)

Comment: What do You mean by `name of the file-input method I'm using isn't recognized`?

Comment: It's two seperate files.  filetest.php is the bottom php script.  What I mean is that it throws the following error message:  Undefined index: uploadfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually realized that if I added the MAX_FILE_SIZE input above my file input property that it would allow me to decide how large of a file I could use.  I then decided to go ahead and set it to 50MB (pretty big I know) and added a '/' into all of my input tags and for some reason it just started working.  It was pretty sweet.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<form action="filetest.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="uploadfile" type="file" >
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="test">
</body>
</html>

<html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    try{
        if( $_FILES['uploadfile']['size'] != 0 )
        {
            $directory = 'localhost/HoneysProject/rosterpics' ;
            move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $directory.$_FILES['uploadfile']['name']) ;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception( "No file was uploaded" ) ;
        }
    }
    catch( Exception $error )
    {
        echo $error ;
    }
}
?>
</html>
```